# Default to [fixed letter spacing], Inform 7 (6L38)

Tags: inform7

Prior to build 6L38, I was able to get ~90% of the text produced to default to fixed letter spacing, by starting the source off with

```
When play begins: say fixed letter spacing.
```

This resulted in the majority of the text defaulting to monospace.

Now that I've updated to 6L38 this doesn't seem to work anymore.

Is there a better / working way of getting all the text printed to be in fixed letter spacing?
At the moment I've had to do this by making sure all my text begins with [fixed letter spacing], including creating printed names for rooms. As you can guess, this isn't the best solution.

EDIT: Turns this is happening because I'm now using glulx (my source is too large for z-code now).

So, the proper question would be "How does one get glulx to default to monospace for everything?"

Comment: Okay, so this is happening because I'm now using glulx (my source is too large for z-code now).

Answer (score 4):

This was so much easier once I'd gone for a walk and stopped staring at it...

```
Include Glulx Text Effects by Emily Short

Table of User Styles (continued)
style name  fixed width
normal-style    true
header-style    true
bold-style  true
```

and done.